# Python Replace multiple words in the list

Tags: python

Below is the code, which i was trying out, but i am not getting the expected results.

```
import re

def multiwordReplace(text, wordDic):
    """
    take a text and replace words that match a key in a dictionary with
    the associated value, return the changed text
    """
    rc = re.compile('|'.join(map(re.escape, wordDic)))
    def translate(match):
        return wordDic[match.group(0)]
    return rc.sub(translate, text)


wordDic = {
'ANGLO': 'ANGLO IRISH BANK',
'ANGLO IRISH': 'ANGLO IRISH BANK'
}
def replace(match):
    return wordDic[match.group(0)]
    #return ''.join(y for y in match.group(0).split())


str1 = {'ANGLO IRISH CORP PLC - THIS FOLLOWS THE BANK NATIONALIZATION BY THE GOVT OF THE REPUBLIC OF IRELAND'
        'ANGLO CORP PLC - THIS FOLLOWS THE BANKS NATIONALIZATION BY THE GOVT OF THE REPUBLIC OF IRELAND'}

for item in str1:
    str2 = multiwordReplace(item, wordDic)
    print str2

    print re.sub('|'.join(r'\b%s\b' % re.escape(s) for s in wordDic), 
        replace, item)
```

**Output:**

**ANGLO  IRISH BANK IRISH** CORP PLC - THIS FOLLOWS THE BANK NATIONALIZATION BY THE GOVT OF THE REPUBLIC OF IRELAND
ANGLO IRISH BANK CORP PLC - THIS FOLLOWS THE BANKS NATIONALIZATION BY THE GOVT OF THE REPUBLIC OF IRELAND

the first one has to give only 'ANGLO  IRISH BANK' and not ANGLO  IRISH BANK IRISH.

Answer (score 1):

Sort so that the longest possible match appears first.

```
longest_first = sorted(wordDic, key=len, reverse=True)
rc = re.compile('|'.join(map(re.escape, longest_first)))
```